# Como realizar un query de count en laravel

Tags: jquery, sql, laravel

Necesito una ayuda para crear un query o alguna forma de realizar un conteo.
Contexto:

Tengo dos tablas:
usuario: donde tengo mis usuario o trabajadores
trabajo: donde asignaré una labor a realizar a un usuario con estados (completo, en proceso, error, etc).

Mi problema nace cuando quiero pasar en un select a mi vista a mis empleados: eso lo puedo realizar de forma fácil, pero a la par necesito saber los trabajos que tienen en curso cada empleado, ejemplo:

```html
    <select class="form-control mb-2" name="" required>
      <option selected> Seleccione el trabajador </option>
      <option value="">Jose - 2 trabajos asignados en curso</option>
      <option value="">Luis - 5 trabajos asignados en curso</option>
</select>
```

De forma que en mi vista se vea de esa forma a mis trabajadores con la cantidad de trabajos asignados pero de menor a mayor.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llenando la información del select? ¿Cuál es tu modelo de trabajadores o usuarios? ¿Cómo está definida la relación entre el trabajador y sus trabajos en el modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la estructura de user es

- Id
- nombre

Y la de trabajo

- id
- id_user
- estado

  $query = DB::table('user', 'u')->select('count(t.id_user) as numerodetrabajos', 'u.nombre as nombre')->join('trabajo as t', 'u.id','=','t.id_user')->groupBy('nombre')->orderBy('numerodetrabajos','desc')->get();

Esto devolverá
https://i.stack.imgur.com/71AO3.jpg

Y si quieres querés que también te traiga los que no tienen trabajos solo pon un Left JOIN

Answer (score 0):

es muy simple en caso de que tiene que añadir texto adicional puede usar un foreach

```
public function datosUsers(){

    $users = \App\User::select('id', 'name')->limit(4)->get();
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
      
      $coutn = \App\TrabajoModel::where('users_id', $user['id'])->count();
      $users[$key]['text'] = $user['name'] . ' - ' . $coutn . ' trabajos asignados en curso';

    }

    return response()->json($users, 202);

}
```

con este codigo me vota el siguiente JSON

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "msaavedra",
"text": "msaavedra - 0 trabajos asignados en curso"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "wnarvaez",
"text": "wnarvaez - 1 trabajos asignados en curso"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "will",
"text": "will - 4 trabajos asignados en curso"
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "operador",
"text": "operador - 8 trabajos asignados en curso"
}
]
```